# Matrix row alignment on two sides of an equation

Tags: matrices

1st question : What's wrong and my following equation doesn't appear as in $\LaTeX$

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}  
\left|0,\,0\,\right\rangle\\
\left|1,\!\!-\!1\right\rangle\\
\left|1,\,0\,\right\rangle\\
\left|1,\!\!+\!1\right\rangle 
\end{bmatrix}
       =
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-\rho&+\rho&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&+\rho&+\rho&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\left|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|\frac{1} {2},-\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle_{\beta}\\
\left|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle_{\beta}\\
\left|\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle_{\beta}\\
\left|\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle_{\beta}
\end{bmatrix}
\label{01}   
\end{equation}
```

2nd question : If editing my above equation to appear, how could I align the rows of the matrices on the two sides ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the matrices at the two sides have the same height, you may increase the inter-row distance via `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}`, for example. A side-note: the `\frac{1}{2}` can be written sparingly as `\frac12`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}   

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{bmatrix}  
\left|0,\,0\,\right\rangle\\
\left|1,\!\!-\!1\right\rangle\\
\left|1,\,0\,\right\rangle\\
\left|1,\!\!+\!1\right\rangle 
\end{bmatrix}
       =
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-\rho&+\rho&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&+\rho&+\rho&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\left|\frac12,-\frac12\right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|\frac12,-\frac12\right\rangle_{\beta}\\
\left|\frac12,-\frac12\right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|\frac12,+\frac12\right\rangle_{\beta}\\
\left|\frac12,+\frac12\right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|\frac12,-\frac12\right\rangle_{\beta}\\
\left|\frac12,+\frac12\right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|\frac12,+\frac12\right\rangle_{\beta}
\end{bmatrix}
\label{01}   
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: *"...the \frac{1}{2} can be written sparingly as \frac12."*  : With this spectacular side note, I unloaded at once from the truck of this short equation 16 fractions x 4 braces/fraction = 64 characters. Many thanks.